# TypeScript: mismatch for index lookups using constrained generic

Tags: typescript, generics

In the following example, I can't think of any situation this would not be sound, therefore I would expect this to be allowed.

Can anyone clarify why it is not allowed?

```
type Foo = { foo: number };
type Bar = { bar: number };

type Tag = 'foo' | 'bar';

type MyObject1 = {
    foo: Foo;
    bar: Bar;
};

type MyObject2 = {
    foo: { value: Foo };
    bar: { value: Bar };
};

<T extends Tag>(t: T) => {
    declare const { value }: MyObject2[T];

    // Unexpected type error
    // Type 'Foo | Bar' is not assignable to type 'MyObject1[T]'.
    const desired: MyObject1[T] = value;
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvKAzBAuKA7AVwFsAjCAJygF8BuAKFEigCEBDSldE93Q0i6vQbhoAFVYBzZFADkWODKgAfWd3IyhjaAFkQAeRIArCAGNgARmmo6UW5hywE9O1DW425erTrCmug8ZmAExWNnbyuOgAbqwANgQQuPCI3i5uaFAx8Yks7IJ03nQAPKJQEAAewBB4ACYAzlDiEgB8ABTAuKIAlMjNaGG2Naax7NAmcHh1wBlZCdS4-kamwEEA2qIAukIuAPQ7UACqeBWQZhA1UFpl5ORw5ANQe40issnKuepQAJYNeHDTrDqdS+EjwrBIsWgwEQVxki0CFnWGxkADoHuNJtMhsDyOcFvolmZzEjpLMIF4aEA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a side effect of [Improve soundness of indexed access types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769). It's not so much that this specific assignment is unsound, but that since you type `desired` as `MyObject1[T]` it is assignable by definition to the property value of an object of type `MyObject1`. So if this assignment were allowed it can lead to issues elsewhere:

```
const example = <T extends Tag>(t: T, { value }: MyObject2[T]) => {
    // Unexpected type error
    // Type 'Foo | Bar' is not assignable to type 'MyObject1[T]'.
    const desired: MyObject1[T] = value; 
    let myObj1!: MyObject1;
    myObj1[t] = desired; // this is where the problem would occur, since T can be a union. 
}

example<Tag>("foo", { value: { bar: 0 }}); // this call brings myObj1 to an invalid state myObj1['foo'] will be of type Bar
```

The option to let `MyObject1[T]` still be a union of possible values and error only on assignment would have the unfortunate consequence of making it impossible to represent 'a value that is assignable as an object value', so this code would be invalid (and impossible to type):

```
const setProperty = <T extends Tag>(t: T, v: MyObject1[T]) => {
    let myObj1!: MyObject1;
    myObj1[t] = v; // This assignment would be invalid if MyObject1[T] was not iself seen as the intersection of all possible values of MyObject1
}
```

If you want to represent a union of possible values of an object use `MyObject1[Tag]`.

```
const example = <T extends Tag>(t: T, { value }: MyObject2[T]) => {
    const desired: MyObject1[Tag] = value; 
}
```

Depending on what you need to do next you might need a type assertion at some point, but without more of the code to understand exactly what you want to do it is hard to tell if you can express is without assertions or if it is indeed type safe or just a limitation of the type sistem.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! In my original example, the function only receives one parameter (unlike in your `example` function), so the assignment will technically always be valid—it's just that we can't tell the compiler this fact. Is that fair to say?

Comment: @OliverJosephAsh exactly. The compiler tracks only types. And from the types it is not apparent that the  compiler is dealing with your safe case or with the unsafe case I present.

Comment: @OliverJosephAsh Are you planning to award the bounty? If I can help with anything else let me know 

Comment: Done, sorry to keep you waiting!

Comment: @OliverJosephAsh no problem, thanks for awarding 

Answer (score 0):

Set aside for the moment that you cannot use `declare` at that part of the code, it appears that currently TypeScript does not have enough intelligence to know that what you're doing is OK. You have to manually tell TypeScript that `value` is of the type `MyObject1[T]`.

```
const desired: MyObject1[T] = value as MyObject1[T];
```

See this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvKAzBAuKA7AVwFsAjCAJygF8BuAKFEigCEBDSldE93Q0i6vQbhoAWRAB5EgCsIAY2ABGZGjoBILHFzw49Nd3K425erTrCm4qbIUAmFanUBtANYQQUAJZ4obkHAwoKxl5JQBdXHQAN1YAGwIIXGCbJVd3MOo6MzoAE3lY9mg5ODwAZ2AoOBkkyRC7IQAeABUoCAAPYAg8HNLfdwCg2pTFAD4ACmBcJoBKZBHVNViICpj46BQq6SdgMIA6VYShNQB6Y6gAOTgAdyhgAAtPXseoCQBpXfVisoq80s9yCA5GrWUKKJxNDIoA7QVi9ZKg8FhUz0IA); I also made some minor modification there.